# Driver não espera a página ser carregada para prosseguir

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

Olá, estou utilizando o Selenium para fazer alguns testes e depois exportando o código para o eclipse. Estou tentando dar um getText em uma página que utiliza ajax usando o xpath, e depois estou tentando autenticar com o assertTrue, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que a página carregue totalmente antes de prosseguir para estas etapas (getText e assertTrue), procurei muito no google e no StackOverflow, encontrei diferentes soluções para o problema, tentei muitas mas nenhuma funcionou.

```
@Test
public void a1_testAuthenticationFailureWhenProvidingBadCredentials() throws InterruptedException{
    driver.findElement(By.name("_58_login")).sendKeys("adma");
    driver.findElement(By.name("_58_password")).sendKeys("Password");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 240);
    //waitForJStoLoad();

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 240);
    //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//form[@id='_58_fm']/fieldset/div/div[3]")));

    String ggg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='_58_fm']/fieldset/div/div[3]")).getText();


    assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='_58_fm']/fieldset/div/div[3]")).equals("Authentication failed. Please try again."));
}
```

OBS: ele retorna erro no assertTrue.

Comment: Tenta usar o wait.until mas vc tem que colocar ate que o elemento esteja visivel e nao present